# Chart.js : How I change the x axes ticks labels alignment in any sizes?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

How can I move my labels on my x axes in between another x axes label. Nothing seems to work and I was unable to find anything on the docs. Is there a workaround? I'm using line chart time series.
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/financial.html

Currently, with the code I have its generating the figure below:

```
var cfg = {
            elements:{
                point: {
                    radius: 4
                }
            },
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'vsy',
                        backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                        data: firstData,
                        type: 'line',
                        pointRadius: 2,
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0,
                        borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'de vsy',
                        backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                        data: dataMaker(15),
                        type: 'line',
                        pointRadius: 2,
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0,
                        borderWidth: 2
                    }
                ],

            },
            options: {

                animation: {
                    duration: 0
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        distribution: 'series',
                        offset: true,

                        time: {
                            unit: 'month',
                            displayFormats: {                                
                                month: 'MMM'
                            }
                        },

                        ticks: {

                            autoSkip: true,
                            autoSkipPadding: 75,

                            sampleSize: 100
                        },

                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            drawBorder: false
                        }

                    }]
                },
                tooltips: {
                    intersect: false,
                    mode: 'index',

                }
            }
        };
```

This is what I have now: 
[image: Original]

I want the labels on the x-axis to be on center instead of below the y axis grid line.
[image: Expected]

Thanks to uminder, with his comment it solves the issue but now I have a conflicting tooltip which lie on a same grid. When I hover to april line first point it shows me mar 30 which lies just above it and vice versa.
[image]

I fixed it by changing the mode to `nearest` but why is it activating the another point?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option you're looking for is [`offsetGridLines`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration).

> If `true`, grid lines will be shifted to be between labels.

```
xAxes: [{
  ... 
  gridLines: {
    offsetGridLines: true
  }
```

In most cases, this produces the expected result. Unfortunately it doesn't work for time axes as documented in [Chart.js issue #403](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5490). Thanks to Antti Hukkanen, there exists a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/ahukkanen/fe69a70c3708b32210fd18860ba609c5).

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet to see how it works.

```js
function generateData() {
  var unit = 'day';
  function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  function randomPoint(date, lastClose) {
    var open = randomNumber(lastClose * 0.95, lastClose * 1.05).toFixed(2);
    var close = randomNumber(open * 0.95, open * 1.05).toFixed(2);
    return {
      t: date.valueOf(),
      y: close
    };
  }
    
  var date = moment().subtract(1, 'years');
  var now = moment();
  var data = [];
  for (; data.length < 600 && date.isBefore(now); date = date.clone().add(1, unit).startOf(unit)) {    
    data.push(randomPoint(date, data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1].y : 30));
  }
  return data;
}

var TimeCenterScale = Chart.scaleService.getScaleConstructor('time').extend({
  getPixelForTick: function(index) {
    var ticks = this.getTicks();
    if (index < 0 || index >= ticks.length) {
      return null;
    }
    // Get the pixel value for the current tick.
    var px = this.getPixelForOffset(ticks[index].value);

    // Get the next tick's pixel value.
    var nextPx = this.right;
    var nextTick = ticks[index + 1];
    if (nextTick) {
      nextPx = this.getPixelForOffset(nextTick.value);
    }

    // Align the labels in the middle of the current and next tick.
    return px + (nextPx - px) / 2;
  },
});
// Register the scale type
var defaults = Chart.scaleService.getScaleDefaults('time');
Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType('timecenter', TimeCenterScale, defaults);

var cfg = {
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: generateData(),
      type: 'line',
      pointRadius: 0,
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'timecenter',
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          stepSize: 1,
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM'
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index'
    }
  }
};
var chart = new Chart('chart1', cfg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: hey Thanks bunch. I have updated my question a bit. I ran into a problem and I wondered if it's occuring with what we changed.

Comment: @Rey Young: My answer describes a work around for an existing bug in the Chart.js library. This workaround really only addresses the labels offset and it's perfectly possible that  the new tooltip issue is related to it. I'm glad, using `mode: 'nearest'` solved this tooltip problem.

Answer (score 0):

For [chartJs v3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/GridLineOptions.html#offset) you can use `offset` property:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    grid: {
        offset: true
    }
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `getPixelForOffset` has been removed from chart.js private APIs,
see [changes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

So the answer provided by uminder requires an update and is obsolete, unless one wants to use previous versions of chart.js.